# Append backend file with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, append

How can I append to a backend text file with React? If the file doesn't exist, it should be created. Here's a sample code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const createResponsesRecord = (
        data1,
        data2
    ) => {
    var data = {
        created: Date().toLocaleString(),
        data1: data1,
        data2: data2
    };
    axios.post("database.json", JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

I'd like to update/append file `"database.json"` and not overwrite it.

Comment: a LOT of detail is missing from your question. We are in a _client & server_ world. This is not a question for a client (React) capability. Files are read, written, appended etc. on the server by server based code.

Comment: Got it. I'm new to React, and I thought it could handle this situation. Thanks!

Comment: For this use case if you do not want to create a backend and database and just want a nice simple react application i would recommend using `json-server` for development purposes and if you want something you'll actually publish you can take a look at `firebase`, good luck out there!

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution to get started (without a database like Firebase). That's why I asked about updating a simple text file.

Comment: By the way, I'm looking into a Flask-based approach like the one described in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-reactjs-with-flask-api/. :)